# AMPscript variable name illegal character error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Please can someone help identify why I'm getting the error:

> A variable name is not a valid because contains illegal characters. Variable names must begin with the @ symbol followed by one or more letters, numbers, or underscores. Variable Name: <*

On the following AMPscript:

```ampscript
%%[ VAR @VoucherPrefix, @Output, @CodeId

SET @CodeId = CodeId
SET @VoucherPrefix = VoucherPrefix

IF @VoucherPrefix == "ST20G1" THEN
SET @Output = 'Grade I Season Ticket'

ELSEIF @VoucherPrefix == "ST20G2" THEN
SET @Output = 'Grade II Season Ticket'

ELSEIF @VoucherPrefix == "ST20G3" THEN 
SET @Output = 'Grade II Season Ticket'

ELSEIf @VoucherPrefix == "ST20G4" THEN
SET @Output == 'Grade IV Season Ticket'

ENDIF 


]%% %%=v(@Output)=%%
```

Comment: Looks like the error is occurring somewhere else in your code.  I'd also wrap your personalization strings in AttributeValue() -- e.g. `AttributeValue("CodeId")`

Answer (score 1):

You should only use double equality characters as logical operators. Simply change:

`SET @Output == 'Grade IV Season Ticket'`

To:

`SET @Output = 'Grade IV Season Ticket'`